# Port Absolute Layout to Relative Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-relativelayout, absolutelayout

I have created an App and all my Buttons are in absolute layout. I figured out that when I use the App in different screens , the layout doesn't fit properly. Can anyone help me in converting the Absolute Layout to Relative Layout

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:text="@string/dot"
    android:textSize="14pt"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    android:textColor="#555555"
    android:id="@+id/point"
    android:layout_x="-3dp"
    android:layout_y="426dp" />
```

Comment: can u please post the whole `layout`

Comment: kausik unable to post the pic :(

Comment: u can post a image in any free site and put that link in ur `Question`